# Reload Iframe in Cisco Finesse

Tags: iframe, reload, cisco

I am using Cisco Finesse Application and there I have an **gadget** with Iframe where I have some site.

1. When I am on the tab in Finesse where this gadget is and I reload the link in Iframe its working.
2. But when I am in other tab than Iframe is blank but when I click "Inspect Element in IE" the content of Iframe exists but is not visible.
3. When I change to other tab and come back than the content is visible.

Maybe Somebody knows what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

have you insert something like that?

```
containerServices = finesse.containerservices.ContainerServices.init();
        containerServices.addHandler(finesse.containerservices.ContainerServices.Topics.ACTIVE_TAB, _handleTabVisible); 
        finesse.containerservices.ContainerServices.makeActiveTabReq();
```